# testing with rspec codeschool level 5 challenge 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Here is the base question for the test:

```
Update the spec so that whenever a tweet is created, we verify that email_tweeter is called on the tweet object.  ***I can not alter the models, question, or mailer.***
```

Models:

```
# tweet.rb
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :zombie
  validates :message, presence: true
  attr_accessible :message

  after_create :email_tweeter

  def email_tweeter
    ZombieMailer.tweet(zombie, self).deliver
  end
  private :email_tweeter
end

# zombie.rb
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tweets
  validates :email, presence: true
  attr_accessible :email
end
```

Mailer:

```
class ZombieMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def tweet(zombie, tweet)
    mail(:from => 'admin@codeschool.com',
         :to => zombie.email,
         :subject => tweet.message)
  end
end
```

I keep bouncing around on this and could use a few pointers.  Here is what I have been working with now:  **UPDATED**

```
describe Tweet do
  context 'after create' do
    let(:zombie) { Zombie.create(email: 'anything@example.org') }
    let(:tweet) { zombie.tweets.new(message: 'Arrrrgggghhhh') }

    it 'calls "email_tweeter" on the tweet' do
      tweet.email_tweeter.should_receive(:zombie)
      tweet.save
    end
  end
end
```

And the error message is:

```
Failures:

1) Tweet after create calls "email_tweeter" on the tweet
Failure/Error: tweet.email_tweeter.should_receive(:zombie)
NoMethodError:
private method `email_tweeter' called for #<Tweet:0x000000062efb48>
# zombie_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) '

Finished in 0.26328 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec zombie_spec.rb:6 # Tweet after create calls "email_tweeter" on the tweet
```

Any rspec peeps out there can point me in the right direction as to what I am missing here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
it 'calls "email_tweeter" on the tweet' do
  tweet.should_receive(:email_tweeter)
  tweet.save
end
```

Comment: omfg, thank you so much for your help. That was it.  These tests can be so picky on codeschool.

Comment: Great!! Thank you. :) Hope the answerers appreciate same way.

Comment: would you have any thoughts on this next one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887106/testing-with-rspec-codeschool-level-5-challenge-4  These tests are pain.  They do not seem to follow real life examples 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
it 'calls "email_tweeter" on the tweet' do
  tweet.email_tweeter.should_receive(:zombie)
  tweet.save
end
```

Comment: I just tried that... no luck :(  Thoughts?  I also updated the error and code above as requested.

Comment: ohh, the method is private. `private :email_tweeter` shouldn't be there.

Comment: I can not control the example they provide, I have to figure out how to test it in this context. I can not edit the models :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
  private :email_tweeter
```

You can't test private methods.

Update:

In fact you can test private methods (with `send` or `eval` methods which do not care about privacy), but you shouldn't, as those are part of implementation not the final output. In your tests you should rather save a new tweet an check that email has been sent. implementation details can change with time, it shouldn't affect tests as long as the mail is being send. You can for example try:

```
it 'generates and sends an email' do
  tweet.save
  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.message.should eq tweet.message
end
```

Comment: I can not control the example they provide, I have to figure out how to test it in this context. I can not edit the models :(

Comment: Now the error message is "Did not create a message expectation on `email_tweeter` of `tweet`."  => These challenges can be a pain.